# YouTube Data API v3 with Laravel: redirect URI mismatch

Tags: php, laravel, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I did set up two Google projects, one for `localhost` and the other for production. The local project (`http://localhost`) is working as expected, but the same code on server (`https://example.com`) is throwing the following error:

```
array:2 [▼
  "error" => "redirect_uri_mismatch"
  "error_description" => "Bad Request"
]
```

I have cross verified all the URLs and set them correctly; even after updating from console, I downloaded the new JSON file and waited for a day. Still the same problem.

Not sure what’s wrong; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your code running on `https://example.com`?

Comment: Yes, my code running on server, getting callback from google and it through that error.

Answer (score 0):

Your post implies that you're developing a [server-side web app](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps).

In this case, the error you've shown indicates that the redirect URI you have set for your respective project within Google Developers Console does not match the one your app is actually [sending to the API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#php_1) at the time of invoking the API:

```php
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
$client->addScope(GOOGLE_SERVICE_YOUTUBE::YOUTUBE_FORCE_SSL);
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');
// offline access will give you both an access and refresh token so that
// your app can refresh the access token without user interaction.
$client->setAccessType('offline');
// Using "consent" ensures that your application always receives a refresh token.
// If you are not using offline access, you can omit this.
$client->setApprovalPrompt("consent");
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
```

Make sure the two sides -- the configuration setup within Google Developers Console and app itself -- agree with respect to the redirect URI to be used.

Comment: Yes, I am using the same code it's working on locathost, I have created two projects, two credentials.json respective for local and production have followed exactly same procedure with just URL change. I understand that it gives error related to URL mismatch but I have added it correctly.

Comment: Do the two JSON files have the same value of their `redirect_uri` property?

Comment: No both are different local one have http://localhost/auth/google/callback and server one have server link like https://example.com/auth/google/callback.

Comment: And you call for `$client->setRedirectUri` in your app accordingly (`https:`, not `http:`), right?

Comment: And both your JSON files are of kind `"web"`, not `"installed"` (i.e. you've set both your Google projects to *Web application*)?

Comment: Yes exact same configured except local and server url. And obviously client_id, client_secret, and project_id are different.

Comment: Also, either both redirect URIs (the config one and the one passed on to `setRedirectUri`) have an `/` at the end or, else, both terminate without any `/`; this is to say the the two URIs are identical character by character.

Comment: Thank you stvar, It got fixed, actually problem was with https I was using laravel route name to get the callback url and it was returning http URL, I have created a environment variable and using that.